# Howto detect if iframe is fully expanded or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I got a contenteditable iframe which can be shrinke so that not all of its content is visible.

**Howto can i detect if this iframe is fully expanded or not?**

Comment: Shell your Iframe detect this or the site including the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (height only)

```
function hasScrollBar() {
  var scroll = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
  return ($(document).height() == scroll);
}
```

Using JS:

```
var root= document.compatMode=='BackCompat'? document.body : document.documentElement;
function hasScrollBar() {
    return (root.scrollHeight>root.clientHeight || root.scrollWidth>root.clientWidth);
}
```